# Add custom version information to "Special Build Description" property of the final exe C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, build

Application is a C# .Net 3.5 WCF Service.

I'd like to dynamically add some build information to appear in the "Special Build Description" property of the final exe. I.e. I'd like to right click on the file and see this information in the version tab for the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a great question, just like my updated question the other day...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305969/add-custom-version-information-to-c-application :)